# Importing typescript files in preload script using Electron

Tags: javascript, typescript, webview, electron, electron-vue

I currently have a `preload.js` script that basically adds variables to the `window` object for a webview. What I want to do is import a typescript file inside the preload script. The preload only supports commonjs syntax.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

I tried to transpile the file and access the webpack output but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the best solution I found was using an external package. First I did publishing it to npm and now I'm using `yarn workspaces` and simply requiring my package inside `preload.js`

`const = { MyClass } = require('my-workspace-package')`

and then I can use it freely inside the file (and also inject it into my `window` object for instance)